# Logo needed for community ads!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, sponsorship-and-advertising, design

Since almost 9 years ago, Science Stack Exchanges have been advertising other Science Stack Exchanges that are still in Beta:

[image]

Currently we are using the default image automatically generated by Area51, but it seems it would be much nicer if we had a custom logo.

**Update:** Our Community Ad on Physics.SE (slightly different from the Area51-generated logo) is performing worse than all of the other community ads in terms of clicks/day (in some cases other ads are getting 2x as many clicks/day as us):

[image]

**Is anyone here able to make one? Perhaps people can answer with logo ideas?**

Comment: C'mon, two weeks are past and not a single answer! (Don't look at me, though, I have neither the talent, nor the tools or time. :))

Comment: I appreciate your enthusiasm @stafusa!

Comment: Is this still an open problem?

Comment: @TristanMaxson yes it is!

Comment: [Community Promotion Ads — 2020](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4660/4945) doesn't use the right name or format. It's distorted, but possibly needs some kind of update.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if someone has created a logo. I didn't see any logo being put on the site so I guess the opportunity is still open.

Here is one of my tries at it. It represents the convergence criteria:

[image]

Post your comments on the same.

Comment: +1. I like it. It's a good start. Maybe the community has other opinions about what should go in the text (maybe  $H\psi = E \psi$ and a classical MD equation). I do like the background though! I think it should also say "Matter Modeling" and "Stack Exchange" somewhere. Or "Modeling Matters". Where did the background come from?

Comment: @NikeDattani Its good that you like it. The background was taken from pexels.com, a non-copyrighted stock photos repository. I did an inversion and a gaussian blur. The foreground is made via the online latex equation maker. I though of including the schrodinger's equation but wouldnt that be more inclined towards the physics community? All improvements are welcome. Everthing was put together using google drawing.

Comment: It would not just be the Schroedinger equation: the comment said it would also have a classical MD equation, maybe: $r^p = r^{(i)} + v^{(i)}\Delta t  + \frac{1}{2} a \Delta t^2$. We do have a GitHub repository where we can collaborate on improving the picture: https://github.com/HPQC-LABS/Modeling_Matters. If you can add all the materials for this logo in a folder called "Logo", then I can maybe try to add some things to it.

Comment: @NikeDattani I've added the link of the google drawing notebook to the github repo. You can take it from there. If I add in the exported image you wont be able to edit it.

Comment: It says "You need access", so maybe you can make it open? Also maybe you can make a folder and put the current .png version of the logo in there. I understand that we can't edit it, but we can keep updating it there so that we have a "version history" of the logo, as we collaboratively make it better. This way we can go back to an old version easily. Maybe Google's system allows that type version history too. I'm just more familiar with GitHub.

Answer (score 3):

Designed this! Hope you like it :)

[image]

Comment: That's really good !!! The "QE" near the lowest electron seems not to be centred, but it's not a very big deal. However, is this 600 x 500? It needs to be 600 x 500 for the Stack Exchange community promotion ads!

Comment: Hey, I will centre the QE, adjust the aspect ratio as 600X500, and will then email it to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my try. Tried drawing it on a paper.

[image]

I think it would do better with a good background or better drawing skills.
Please feel free to edit and improvise.

Comment: I love it!!!!!!

Comment: @Nike Thank you! :)